# Thicker X-Axis with Charts.js

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

Using the Chart.bundle.js script (documentation [here](http://www.chartjs.org)), I've created a Line Chart within a  object in javascript.  Furthermore, my x-axis is numerical, ranging from -100 to 100.  It is very important to me that there be a clear distinction between negative and positive numbers, and so I am trying to show a clear, bold x-axis on my Chart object; however, it doesn't seem like Chart.js provides this feature-or perhaps I just cannot find it.  Is there any way of making a thicker x-axis?  I am open to both conventional solutions as well as hacky ones, if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your options, you can set the `lineWidth` option:

```
options: {
   scales: {
      xAxes: [{ 
        gridLines: { lineWidth: 50 },
     }]
  }
}
```

And the [corresponding docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html)

Answer (score 1):

for x-axis to be more thicker we set in yAxes gridLines this line
*zeroLineWidth:2*
for y-axis to be more thicker we set in xAxes gridlines this line
*zeroLineWidth:2*

*documentation:*

[enter link description here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html)

```
yAxes: [{           
 gridLines: {
    zeroLineWidth:2
}           
}],
 xAxes: [{
  gridLines: {
    zeroLineWidth:2
 }
}]
```

Comment: Please provide some context to the code you posted, don't just poste stand-alone code